# Getting Data Echoed every time a condition is met in PHP through AJAX

Tags: php, jquery, html, ajax

A POS software overwrites the orders in a text fie. I am trying to make a Kitchen Display which shows the orders.
My php script reads from that text file...
A comparision is made after every 1 second using `sleep(1);` to check if a new order has arrived.

```
<?php

$f1 = fopen("G:/order.txt", 'r');    
$firstLine1 = fgets($f1);
fclose($f1);

sleep(1);

$f2 = fopen("G:/order.txt", 'r');
$firstLine2 = fgets($f2);

fclose($f2);

if($firstLine1 != $firstLine2) {    
    $fh = fopen("G:/order.txt", "r");    
    echo "<div>";        
    while ($line = fgets($fh)) {        
        echo ($line);
    }
    fclose($fh);
    echo "</div>";
}    
?>
```

And using Ajax I run that script every 1 mini second.

```
<script>
function loadDoc(){
var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
    $("p").before(this.responseText);
}
};
xhttp.open("GET", "order.php", true);
xhttp.send();
}
window.setInterval(function(){
loadDoc()
}, 1);
</script>
```

The problem is that that around 50 Divs are created for every new order where it should be just 1.

1 Div per order.

Please help me I'm messed up.

Comment: orders in a _text file_...does POS stand for "Point of Sale" or "Piece of S***"?? :-) Why no database? Anyway your PHP script should just read _once_ from the file during each execution, and then return any orders it has not found during any previous executions (for that, maybe the ajax client needs to tell it the ID of the last order it received, or you could use a SESSION variable). And running the ajax call every millisecond is crazy - you know for a fact it the previous call cannot return before that's complete, you'll be overloading your server and also getting crazy concurrency issues.

Comment: Instead wait until the previous call has completed before running it again (simply call loadDoc() again from the readystatechange callback instead of using setInterval). Or you could change it to only run at a longer interval (10 seconds, 30 seconds? It depends how time-critical this data really is)

Comment: I am new to programming can you please rewrite the code.. I’ll be greatful to you!

Comment: I don't actually have enough info, based on your code, to able to do that. Mainly, I don't know how to determine, when reading order.txt, that a line has been read before. Does each line have a unique Order ID contained within it? Do items ever get removed from order.txt? Also, is there any possibility of altering the POS software to store orders in a database instead? That would make this whole thing a lot easier and more reliable.

Comment: The very first line of the code is Unique Order ID.. On this basis only i compare using sleep() to know whether new order has arrived or not.. ( database option is not available).. the key to my algorithm is by comparing the order id after every(0.5) seconds.

Comment: so the whole file only contains 1 single order at a time? And it gets over-written every time a new order is placed? How do you keep a record of previous orders???

Comment: Yes you are right... its get over written.. (I dont need any record of my orders)

Comment: I see. How do you deal with returns, or incorrect orders, amendments, queries from customers etc, if you have no records of any of your transactions? Is that stored separately, away from this file? Or is this just a demo or something? Sorry I'm just curious how you can get away with such a basic implementation. Meanwhile I will try to think of how you can solve your problem with the current version

Comment: Personally I wouldn't put your email on here - it can be crawled by spam bots and used to receive junk mail, or for someone to try and hack your account. But anyway...what happens if the device displaying the page in the kitchen crashes, or someone closes it by accident during the preparation of orders, or a customer queries the order, or you want to prepare an automatic receipt based on that order (instead of writing it again). In all those cases, the data is lost with no way to retrieve it. You're also throwing away valuable data for analysis of the kitchen's efficiency

Comment: It's really quite easy to set up a basic database table which will just record the details of orders instead of pasting them into a throwaway text file. Then there's no problem, even if the display system crashes with orders on screen, they can be retrieved next time it is loaded. You can also do things like mark orders as processed / completed etc, which again should make things run more smoothly and make it possible to investigate problems. There are so many advantages to a database approach, and it's such a straightforward change, that I really think it would be crazy not to do it.

Comment: Even if the customer doesn't want all those features now, you can bet 100% that they will want it later. And then it will be easy for you to provide them. And the least you can do is give them some basic reliability in case the system crashes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think this will work better. Since you're making repeated ajax calls to run the same script, it doesn't make much sense to read repeatedly from the file during each run. Plus your comparison doesn't make any reference to what happened last time the script ran, which, combined with the insane frequency of ajax requests, is resulting in endless duplicate results.

Instead, compare the order ID retrieved on each run to the one retrieved on the previous run. Also, you need to increase the interval between requests, otherwise you'll swamp your server, and also run the risk of concurrency problems where your next request tries to begin before the previous one finishes (don't forget that ajax calls run asynchronously).

**PHP**

```
<?php
session_start(); //enable sessions
$f1 = fopen("G:/order.txt", 'r');    
$firstLine = fgets($f1);

//check whether a previous order ID has been stored during this session.
if (isset($_SESSION["lastOrderID"])) {
  //if the order ID in the file is the same as the last stored one in the session, don't send any data to the client
  if ($firstLine == $_SESSION["lastOrderID"]) 
  {  
    echo "";
    fclose($f1);
    die();
  }
}

echo "<div>";
echo $firstLine;      
while ($line = fgets($f1)) {
  echo ($line);
}
echo "</div>";

//store the last order ID in the session
$_SESSION["lastOrderID"] = $firstLine;
fclose($f1);
```

**JavaScript**

```
<script>
function loadDoc(){
  var xhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
      $("p").before(this.responseText);
    }
  };
  xhttp.open("GET", "order.php", true);
  xhttp.send();
}

window.setInterval(loadDoc, 10000); //refresh every 10 seconds. You can decrease the interval if you like, but don't make it so short that it regularly starts another request before the previous one has completed. You can use your browser's network tools to see how the long requests normally take, and use that to help you decide on a suitable value. Leave some headroom for the occasional slowdown.
</script>
```

Bear in mind that this will only work for the duration of the session - i.e. normally just for as long as the browser window is open, or until the session times out. You can google how to increase the session timeout if necessary. If you require anything more persistent than this (i.e. to remember the last Order ID between sessions) then you should use another text file, or a database in order to record this information, instead of the session.

I'd also like to re-iterate here my concern that your POS software seems overly simplistic, at least based on the details given in the question, and that for audit and other fairly obvious purposes, it might make sense to persist historical records of all orders using a database, instead of over-writing a text file each time a new order is entered.